# Changing Bin Sizes Using Hour:Minute In ggplot histogram

Tags: r, time, ggplot2, histogram

I am creating a histogram of when something occured, so the x-axis is time in hour:minute format. I am trying to change the bins to 15 minutes instead of 5 but am not able to do so. The binwidth argument in geom_histogram seems to not respond. Is there a way to change the bin size when dealing with H:M? If not, I can represent the minutes as percentage of the hour, for example, 9:45 AM would be 9.75, though I would prefer to keep the hour:min format.  Thank you.

[image]

The below code will reproduce the histogram.

```
temp <- structure(list(unique.data.Date. = structure(c(14615, 14616, 
14617, 14622, 14623, 14635, 14636, 14637, 14642, 14650, 14651, 
14658, 14659, 14662, 14663, 14671, 14672, 14677, 14679, 14683
), class = "Date"), Time = structure(c(2L, 16L, 11L, 9L, 3L, 
8L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 16L, 3L, 4L, 52L, 13L, 8L, 17L, 4L
), .Label = c("09:35", "09:40", "09:45", "09:50", "09:55", "10:00", 
"10:05", "10:10", "10:15", "10:20", "10:25", "10:30", "10:35", 
"10:40", "10:45", "10:50", "10:55", "11:00", "11:05", "11:10", 
"11:15", "11:20", "11:25", "11:30", "11:35", "11:40", "11:45", 
"11:55", "12:00", "12:05", "12:10", "12:15", "12:20", "12:30", 
"12:35", "12:40", "12:45", "12:50", "13:00", "13:15", "13:20", 
"13:30", "13:40", "13:45", "14:05", "14:10", "14:15", "14:20", 
"14:35", "14:40", "14:45", "14:50", "15:20", "15:25", "15:30", 
"15:35", "15:45", "15:50", "16:00"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("unique.data.Date.", 
"Time"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(temp, aes(x=temp$Time)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(stat="bin"), fill="lightblue", binwidth = 50, color="grey50")
```

Comment: Those items in "Time"  are not times but rather factors.  There really is no natural notion of `binwidth` or `range` for a factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you expected:

```
 ggplot(temp, aes(x=as.POSIXct(temp$Time,format="%H:%M"))) + 
    geom_histogram( fill="lightblue", binwidth = 15*60,  # 15 min *60 sec/min
                color="grey50")
```

[image]

Note that these "times" are all on different days, but that the conversion to POSIXct format will implicitly make then all with today's date, so it might not be a good idea to do the conversion in the original dataframe.